# Understanding the logical not operator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

```
const allItems = [
  {id: 'apple', value: ' apple'},
  {id: 'orange', value: ' orange'},
  {id: 'grape', value: ' grape'},
  {id: 'pear', value: ' pear'},
]

function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState(allItems)

  function addItem() {
    const itemIds = items.map(i => i.id)
    setItems([...items, allItems.find(i => !itemIds.includes(i.id))])
```

I am fairly new to JS and I have been working through a React workshop. It is the last line of this code that is confusing me. How should I read !itemIds.includes(i.id)? Maybe it will help to know that later in the code there is an add item button that triggers this function. It only works if an item had already been removed from items.

Comment: includes returns a boolean. The ! flips it. So if includes finds the item, it returns true. So you have `!true` which will return `false`.

Comment: `!itemIds.includes(i.id)` will return true if i.id is not in itemIds.

Answer (score 1):

The ! operator is use as "not". When you do something that must return a boolean (`true | false`), using ! will return the opposite.

In your exemple, `itemsIds.includes(i.id)` will return `true` if i.id is in itemsIds.
So, `!itemsIds.includes(i.id)` will return `false` if i.id is in itemsIds.

FYI, your function addItem will add items to your state items, but only once, cause your `setItems([...items, allItems.find(i => !itemIds.includes(i.id))])` will add every items that are not already in your items array.